# Binary file's hex value won't change using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an issue where my C# code wasn't able to change a hex value in the 13th position.

[image: See the screenshot from HxD Hex editor for further detail]

This is C# my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
        textBox1.Text = fileName;
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = textBox1.Text;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Position = 13;
        stream.WriteByte(0x00);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `stream.Position = 13;` (13 is in decimal)
Your picture is pointing to 13 hex (19 in decimal) so you'll need
`stream.Position = 0x13`